# HTML space needed in fetching the results from URL

Tags: php

I am having a problem in my code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select movie_name from jos_movie");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $movie_name= $row['movie_name'];
        $xmls = simplexml_load_file("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/myapi/$movie_name");
        foreach($xmls->movies->movie as $movies){
        $arrMovie_id= $movies->id;  
      }
          echo $arrMovie_id;
    }
?>
```

If you see I am passing URL to fetch the results for movie ID . When the movie is of single name for example "Ironman" it fetches the correct movie Id "10505" and if the movie name is "Ironman 2' it wont work and gives wrong ID. 
But if I pass movie_name as "ironman%202" it fetches the correct result . How can I get the space problem fix . Since from DB it fetchs  "ironman 2"

I have tried

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $movie_name= urlencode($row['movie_name']);
        $xmls = simplexml_load_file('http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/myapi/'.$movie_name);
```

and

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $movie_name= rawurlencode($row['movie_name']);
        $xmls = simplexml_load_file('http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/myapi/'.$movie_name);
```

its not working :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
$movie_name = urlencode($row['movie_name']);
$xmls = simplexml_load_file('http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/myapi/'.$movie_name);
```

EDIT:

If you want to only get the first (and valid) fetched result, break on a condition in your foreach loop (I guess checking if the id is an integer should be enough):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select movie_name from jos_movie");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $movie_name = rawurlencode(trim($row['movie_name']));
        $xmls = simplexml_load_file("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/myapi/$movie_name");
        foreach($xmls->movies->movie as $movies){
            $arrMovie_id = $movies->id;
            if ($arrMovie_id && is_int($arrMovie_id)) break;
        }
        echo $arrMovie_id;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I made this change while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ $movie_name= urlencode($row['movie_name']); $xmls = simplexml_load_file('api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/myapi/…); it didnt worked :(

Comment: Then try with rawurlencode instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: Could you please give us the movie name before and after rawurlencode?

Comment: Hi I just checked below are the echos 
echo $movie_name; = Dabangg%202%20-- Correct now
echo $xmls; = Nothing -- didnt echo 
echo $arrMovie_id; = 44425 -- Incorrect should be 147405

Comment: Looks like you had a trailing space in your name, remove it with trim before passing it to rawurlencode, it should then work OK! http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Alright, I got it: you query returns you 2 results. The id of the first movie is 147405, of the id of the second movie is 44425, and since you change the value of $arrMovie_id in a foreach loop, the last id will be displayed. If you want to get the first id, break you foreach loop as soon as you read a correct id (see my edit above).

Comment: i want to show first one .. what changes i have to do in code ?

Comment: I checked there are actually 2 movies ID in same XML so its taking the first one. What if I want to take second ID ?

Comment: If you want to take the first AND the second id, use an array to store them or display them within the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines:

```
$movie_name = urlencode($row['movie_name']);
```

That should transform the spaces into %20.  Also if there are any non alpha-numeric values in the movie title, they should also be encoded.

Comment: I made this change 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $movie_name= urlencode($row['movie_name']);
  $xmls = simplexml_load_file('http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/myapi/'.$movie_name);

it didnt worked :(

Comment: Should not really matter whether spaces get converted into `%20` or `+` – most HTTP compliant services should accept both.